# what exception would be appropriate to throw when an android permission is missing?

Tags: java, android, exception, coding-style, android-permissions

Would like to enforce use of permissions and "fail fast" - some older APIs fail silently IIRC - so I came up with :

```
private static void assertPermission(Context ctx, String perm) {
    final int checkPermission = ctx.getPackageManager().checkPermission(
        perm, ctx.getPackageName());
    if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Permission " + perm
            + " is required");
    }
}
```

I would like to use a permission appropriate to the abstraction - and follow effective Java's advice : *Favor the use of standard exceptions.*

- Should I use `IllegalStateException` or is there some more appropriate
  exception ?
- Should I use a checked exception ?

Comment: just my 2 cents: android tends to throw `SecurityException` if there is no permission ... you could do the same ...

Comment: @Selvin: your 2 cents with a justification/denial of my helper method could make for an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Selvin's comment I let android throw the exception - I got :

> 09-20 17:13:39.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1688): java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10064 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

So it indeed appears that android uses [`java.lang.SecurityException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityException.html) - and to be consistent with android I'll have to use this

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic Java exception, I'd use a [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html), which is a [`RuntimeException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) used when an unsupported operation is attempted.

According to the doc, the [`IllegalStateException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is more linked to the VM itself :

> Thrown when an action is attempted at a time when the VM is not in the
>   correct state.

Comment: So no checked exception ?

Comment: Well I've been through all existing exceptions available in Android, and none seems to match better than this one.

Comment: Besides, you don't need a checked exception as the only solution is to change the manifest and recompile the app (unless you make a library with a fallback behavior if the permission is unset). But nothing prevents you to use a try-catch block for this exception

Comment: What about `SecurityException` ?

Comment: The SecurityException is linked to the SecurityManager, which is present in Android for compatibility purpose but is not really used. It is legacy code but have a different meaning although Android permissions are a matter of security too.